# Why is the derivative of a polar function $dy/dx$ and not $dr/d\theta$?

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, complex-analysis, derivatives

I don't understand.

If $r = 2\cos(\theta)$ then why is the derivative:

$dy/dx$? I have a "hypothesis,"

By the polar equation are you really describing a curve in the cartesian plane? So is that why?

Comment: This question is missing vital information: first, the fact that this question is in reaction to a particular treatment of the topic in a particular book, and second, what that book said. Were there literally words anywhere in the book that say, "the derivative of $r=2 \cos \theta$ is $dy/dx$"? If not, what _did_ the book actually say?

Answer (score 4):

$\dfrac {\mathrm dr}{\mathrm d\theta}$ is a perfectly kosher derivative. If you have a set of parametric equations in $x$ and $y$, you can also consider other derivatives.

"Derivative" is ambiguous. There's the derivative of "something" with respect to "something", and often there's more than one useful derivative to consider for a particular problem.

edit: the OP says he or she's looking for the slope of the tangent line. I looked up finding the tangent line of a curve written in polar coordinates in "Calculus" by Larson.

He says, if you have parametric equations at the point you're interested in, and you want to find the slope of the tangent lines, then use:

$\displaystyle \frac {\mathrm dy}{\mathrm dx}= \frac{\frac {\mathrm dy}{\mathrm d\theta}}{\frac {\mathrm dx}{\mathrm d\theta}}$

He actually says more than that, but you can definitely derive everything he says. The moral of the story is that if the book wants $\mathrm dy/\mathrm dx$, you can find it without having $y$ as an explicit function of $x$.

Comment: First time in my loooong life I hear about a kosher derivative ! I like that. Thanks & cheers :-)

Comment: No, in my textbook, it says the derivative of a polar equation is $dy/dx$ not $dr/d\theta$

Comment: There are also halal derivatives? :-)

Comment: Amad, can you put the exact quote of the book in your post?

Comment: Here is a quote of the problem. Find the slope of the line tangent to the curve at $\theta = \pi/3$

Answer (score 0):

Your polar equation is equivalent to *some* cartesian equation. Are you able to find it?

Comment: Yes I am aware, but I want to do this_without_ conversion. So I was asking, when textbooks define this, then there are no "polar-derivates," there are just $dy/dx$ and the polar equation is a parameter? http://books.google.tm/books?id=PTELAAAAQBAJ&pg=PA715&lpg=PA715&dq=10.4+larson+calculus&source=bl&ots=_wyCEOKMlF&sig=MmjHANb03RLlJaTssjnMSEfUzfM&hl=en&sa=X&ei=5vJtVMvgNuLIsQTH9IJQ&ved=0CC0Q6AEwAw#v=onepage&q=10.4%20larson%20calculus&f=false, a little scroll.

Comment: I think that your book is asking by $dy/dx$ ($y$ is a implicitly defined function of $x$) expressed in polar coordinates.